# Linking libraries in Xcode C-lang

Tags: c++, c, xcode, linker

I have a project which makes use of a 3rd party library. I installed it into the system folder (/usr/include) and everything works if I add -lsodium to the command line.

I want to use Xcode but how do I add the dependencies to the product?

Comment: I'd like to know how to make Xcode view this as a dependency too.  Currently, I just stick `-lmylib` in Other Linker Flags, but that's a real hack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode linking against static and dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699389/xcode-linking-against-static-and-dynamic-library)