# How can I work on the same project using both window's visual studio 2017 and mac's Xcode 10.2.1?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, sfml

I'm working on a little larger project for which I would like to use both my pc and MacBook. I synchronize the code using Github. I don't know why but when I try adding new files to my Xcode project(with some previously written code using visual 2017 on windows) it cannot find my sfml library for those files, but it works perfectly fine when I don't include neither of those. I find it really strange because I keep all of these files in the same (original for Xcode project) directory.
I will also mention that I use separate libraries for each platform and both seem to be working fine so it's probably not a problem caused by improper installation of those.

I've already tried setting up new Xcode project like 10 times each time trying to change the order( for example I tried adding SFML before and after including those new files ) or somehow cheat the system to think the very original main.cpp it created is the one from new files but it didn't help.

The error I get is 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found and same for each of the others "parts" of SFML like audio, network, window and system.

I will appreciate any kind of solution which will lets me work on this in these two environments, with reasonable effort for adding new files.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd start by checking if the command used to execute the compiler contains properly set `-I` flag pointing to the SFML include directory.

Comment: Ok that sounds promising. Could you please tell me where to check it in xcode?

Comment: I never used Xcode, so I cannot help you with that, but [this seems to answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060898/xcode-how-to-see-build-command-and-log).