# "linker command failed..." with "ld: file too small" In Xcode 10.0, Swift 4 (Cocoa)

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift4, xcode10

I need some help please. I can't seem to figure out how to fix this clang error in Xcode 10.0, Swift 4 (MacOs Cocoa):

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is a picture of the build log:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

P.S. Please note that I am not using **Cocoa Pods**, but my app does use
**URL**

Comment: If you want an answer, you need to update your question with more information. Does your project use Cocoapods or any other third-party frameworks? If you press Cmd-9, you can select the build and see the low-level steps Xcode takes to build the project. See the following question: [Xcode - how to see build command and log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060898/xcode-how-to-see-build-command-and-log/30084344). Update your question with the contents of the build log for the link step that fails.

Comment: Ok I will, thanks.

Comment: Just added more information. Hope it’s useful.

Comment: The link error says you have an empty object file, `view2.0`. That error implies there was a problem compiling a file `view2.swift`. Update your question with the build log for the build step that compiles `view2.swift`.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question again. I hope it's more helpful this time :)

Comment: You need to show the build log for compiling the file `view2.swift`. All you did was show a longer version of the link step. The linker error is saying you have an empty object file. The length=0 part of the error message is telling you the object file is empty. You need to show the step where the compiler compiles the Swift file to an object file.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Sorry about that

Comment: One problem:  I don’t see the Compile Step

Comment: Wait! Nvm, It worked! All I did was save the "view2.swift" file with CMD+S.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply to my question. It really helped. :)