# React native iOS build error after updating a react native

Tags: ios, react-native

After updating a react-native version, have got some issues while trying to `npm run ios`.

> This is a problem what I've got:

[image]

[image]

> What I Tried:

I have installed `cocoapods`, done `pod deintegrate`, done `pod update` also I have done `pod repo update`. I tried to delete and reinstall `node_modules`. But errors are the same.

While running a `pod install`, I have got this:
[image]

The output of `react native doctor`:

[image]

here is what i have when running in xcode:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

react native info
[image]

content of `pod` file:
[image]

Comment: Try deleting `pods` folder & `.lock` file and `npx pod-install` in the project root

Comment: @RajendranNadar same result unfortunately

Comment: Try `npx react-native doctor` check if there is any error or warning

Comment: Try changing the build setting to legacy and re-run the app

Comment: Can you paste the build log? From Xcode https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084344/5519872

Comment: try 'Product->Clean' in Xcode and then build again?

Comment: Also, paste the content inside the Podfile

Comment: after product clean build - same problem that i added screenshots

Comment: @RajendranNadar pasted pod file content to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235260/discussion-between-rajendran-nadar-and-ian).

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to a new RN version can be quite tricky sometimes. An easy way to do it is to just use this [helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/). You put your old (current) version number into the left textbox on the helper website, and then you also put your new version that you want to upgrade to into the textbox on the right, before clicking the 'Show me how to upgrade!' button.

So in your case what I would suggest you do is to use this helper as a guide for your particular scenario, using your old version and the new one that is giving you the errors. Once you click on the button, it will show you exactly which changes you need to make in order for your project to build successfully. Then you can compare what you have already tried to the guide, perhaps you missed something somewhere.

Comment: He is using expo so `expo upgrade` works in most cases when there is not react-native version change.

Comment: But he mentioned nothing about Expo or `expo upgrade` anywhere in his question though...

Comment: You can see uni-modules in the podfile, so it is expo bareworkflow application

Comment: If it is Expo's bare workflow, then he can still use the RN upgrade helper in my answer. In fact, that is exactly what I use to upgrade my Expo bare workflow app.

Comment: By the way, the library you are referring to, [expo-file-system](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-file-system) can be used and installed on even non Expo RN apps. It is possible to install Expo libraries as npm packages, just like you would any other npm library.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do

1. `cd ios`
2. `pod install --repo-update` or `pod repo update`
3. `pod install`

Or to simplify it with a single cmd you can use `npx pod-install repo update && npx pod-install`

The pod install should run successfully. This happened to me after installing a package & running `npx pod-install`

I just got this error in one of the projects the above steps solved my issue. Try this and let me if any issues.

Comment: Now I have only this problem `Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app`

Comment: To fix that use `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/` Make sure the path is correct I am assuming Xcode.app is inside the applications folder because it is the default path until you change it.

Comment: the same result:(

Comment: This is a new project? The version of react native? Did you try to unlink all the packages using `yarn react-native unlink <package>`? Any issue with doctor cmd for ios? Try to build the app through xcode

Comment: Also try to restart the pc sometimes it works, happens with me also.

Comment: have updated a question with xcode run info & react native info

Comment: the project is not new

Comment: and how do i know which packages do i have to unlink?

Comment: If RN is above v0.60 unlink all that supports auto-linking, if there is any build folder inside the ios folder delete it & also try deleting the derived data folder of the project.

Comment: how do i know which supports autolinking and which is not?

Comment: so you mean, i have to unlink from every dependency i have in a packga json?