# Xcode test build fails

Tags: swift, xcode

Every time I run `cmd + u` I get this error:

[image]

If I run `cmd + b` the build is successful.

I tried to install for testing same pods as debug build but it seems that is not the problem. Also clean derived data also does not work.

Please, if you have any clue share it. Also feel free for asking about more information.

Edited:

```
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'Lottie'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'Airship'

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you examine the full log, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060898/xcode-how-to-see-build-command-and-log

Answer (score 0):

In podfile, after stopping using inherit from test target, and set this one to use Lottie and Airship directly, it works properly. In this way I can use this frameworks with my tests.