# how to can i get error logs/stack trace from xcode?

Tags: swift, flutter

I'm developing a flutter project and i'm not so familiar with xcode. I'm always getting errors in xcode but dont have any clue what the error is because im not getting any logs from it to be able to see why the build failed...
[image]

what I've tried that didn't work:

1. went to Xcode > preference then checkmarked the show debugger with console view
   [image]
2. went to View > Debug are > activate console.

on the side panel i'm only getting this:

[image]

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The area you are pointing at the first screen is a debugger/console view. It's used when your app is already built and running. The problem you are facing is a compile-time fail and related to one of the build phases, probably you have a script that is running during the build and it fails. Like this:

[image]

To diagnose the problem you should inspect full logs. You can find them at the last tab of side table. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060898/xcode-how-to-see-build-command-and-log) for full details.